# why I am unable to push data in mongoose schema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

```
const articleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title:String,
  ques:String,
  ans:String,
  details:[
   {
    author:String,
   employeeId:Number,
   age:Number,
   gmailId:String
 } ]
});

const Article =  mongoose.model("Article", articleSchema);
```

I want that if two documents has same 'title' value then push the second document's data(ignoring title , ques ,ans ) ( only details) into first one.
If not, then let it save as another document.

Below is its implementation...

---

```
app.post("\postDocument",function(req,res){

  const obj= {
    author:req.body.author,
    employeeId:req.body.employeeId,
    age:req.body.age,
    gmailId:req.body.gmailId
  };
  Article.updateOne({title:req.body.title},
    { title:req.body.title,
      ques:req.body.ques,
      ans:req.body.ans,
      $push:{details:obj}
  },
    function(err,foundarticles){
      if(!err)
      {
        res.send("updated successfully");
      }
      else
      {
        createnewArticle();
       }
  });

  function createnewArticle(){

  const newArticle = new Article({
    title:req.body.title,
    ques:req.body.ques,
    ans:req.body.ans,
    details:[
      obj
    ]
  });

   newArticle.save();
})
```

I am taking data from form and in post body I am checking whether title 's value exists . If it exists , push the details array into existing document .
If not, then create the document and save.